# C# Parsing a IHttpActionResult Json Object returned by a method call

Tags: c#, json, json.net, asp.net-web-api2

I'm returning a Json object from a method call within another method and would like to ask how to access the properties created within the returned Json object?

I understand that I could return a non Json object with the required properties however how would I access the anonymous type passed into the returned Json

```
    [HttpPost]
    public IHttpActionResult PhoneReminder([FromUri] RegisterInterest PhoneReminderValues, int RYI_WebID)
     {

            var JsonReturned = object1();
            // access the Json object like this -> JsonReturned.message
            ....
           //rest of code

     }

    public IHttpActionResult object1()
     {
       return new Json(new {message ="hello world"});
     }
```

Comment: This looks like a job for [Json.NET](https://www.newtonsoft.com/json).

Comment: @DanielShillcock This works if the object is serialized with JSON.net  then deserializeObject works and I can access the message property like in the example above however how can I access the IHttpActionResult Json Object?

Comment: Why not move the logic from `object1()` out into a private method that returns the object, have `object1()` call that private method and return the result? Then in `PhoneReminder` you can also call that same private method, that way you don't have pointless JSON serialisation followed by deserialisation

Comment: @succeed This is an 
[XY problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem) that hides a deeper problem. If both actions belong to the same ApiController then the shared functionality can be extracted into it's own function/service and used by both actions. There really is no need for all the heavy lifting serializing and deserializing in the controller. Review the current design choices.

Comment: @p3tch Yes that is a solution however say for consistency purposes and general interest is there a way to access this Json object that is returned

Answer (score 1):

Get Newtonsoft.Json from NuGet.

And then you can do it this way:

```
public async Task<T> GetObjectFromContent<T>(HttpContent content) where T: class
{
    string response = await content.ReadAsStringAsync();
    if (string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(response))
        return null;

    try
    {
        T obj = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<T>(response);
        return obj;
    }
    catch(JsonSerializationException)
    {
        return null;
    }          
}
```

Firstly I get a string response from HttpContent. It's really just a json in string.
Then JsonConvert.DeserializeObject is used. Of course you have to declare first the class. For example, if you have Json like this:

```
{
    "FirstName" : "John",
    "SecondName" : "Black"
}
```

then you have to create class:

```
class Person
{
    public string FirstName { get; set; }
    public string LastName { get; set; }
}
```

And call this method (GetObjectFromContent) with Person as T.
Your class should have a parameteless constructor.
You can also give differen names for your properties, but you will have to decorate them with attribute JsonProperty

Comment: I can also return a JsonConvert.SerializeObject();
            and then deserialized JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<>(); However, im interested in specifically accessing the anonymous type passed into the Json method returned in my example

Answer (score 0):

```
Use Nuget Newtonsoft.Json
```

if suppose your JSON object is like:

```
HttpResponseMessage response;
var jsonObject = await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
```

Now suppose you have one property "FirstName" in the JSON which you want to access

You can do it like below:

```
using Newtonsoft.Json.Linq;

var parsedJsonObject = JObject.Parse(jsonObject);
var firstName =  parsedJsonObject["FirstName"];
```